# Product of a row within a Ragged (jagged) Array

Tags: java, multidimensional-array, methods, product, jagged-arrays

I had a challenge question in my CS course this semester that is a review question from last semester, but the question is: "Given a ragged array, find if any row within the array has a product of 48 and if so return that row number. If no rows contain a product of 48, return -1." This is what I have so far.

```
public class RaggedProducts {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    int[][] a = {{3, 9},
                {100},
                {1, 4, 6, 2},
                {23, 3, 8}};
    System.out.println(product(a));
}

/*
 * finds if parameter array has a row which the numbers within that row
 * have a product of 48, returns row integer value. If no rows have a
 * product of 48, returns -1.
 */
public static int product(int[][] ragged) {
    int product = 1;

    for (int i = 0; i < ragged.length; i++) {
        // EDIT: I got my answer, I had to add "product = 1" here
        for (int j = 0; j < ragged[i].length; j++) {
            product *= ragged[i][j];
            if (i > 0) { // what to do here to reset product value whenever "i" changes
                         // "i > 0" is just a placeholder, I know it doesn't make sense
                product = 1;
            }
            if (product == 48) {
                return i; // I want to return the value 2
            }
        }
    }
    return -1;
}
```

}

If I set the first row in the jagged array to have a product of 48, the program works, but I'm confused on how to go about resetting the product field to 1 after the row changes. Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: The variable `i` changes on every loop. For the purpose of resetting `product` you don't have to care about the value of `i`, you can simply reset it on every loop of your outer for-loop.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You seem to be confused as to how iterating over a 2D array works. Your two loops basically do this:

```
for each row i do {
    //you can do something here too!
    for each cell j in row i do {
        ...
    }
    //...and here!
}
```

So if you want to reset product to when you begin iterating over a next row, just do it before the second for loop in your code.

Also, now your program returns a row if the product is equal *or greater than* 48. From what I understand that is not what you want. So you should check for equality *after* iterating over cells in a row (after the second for loop but inside the first for loop).

Btw, java supports syntax more similar to my pseudocode. You can write

```
for (int[] row : ragged) {
    for (int value : row) {
        //do something
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, that was a really simple fix and I got my answer!

Answer (score 0):

```
 public static int product(int[][] ragged) {
    int product = 1;

    for (int i = 0; i < ragged.length; i++) {
      for (int j = 0; j < ragged[i].length; j++) {
        product *= ragged[i][j];


      }
      if (product == 48) {
        return i; // I want to return the value 2
      }else{
        product=1;
      }
    }
    return -1;
  }
```